# when I click on the icon, It was not redirected to the link. How can I do that?

Tags: reactjs

I have added link in the icons, but when I clicked on the icon, it was not redirected to the page.

```
          <i class="fa-brands fa-github"><a href="https://github.com/MonoTech71"></a></i>

          <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"><a href="#"></a></i>

          <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"><a href="#"></a></i>

        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to wrap the icon in `anchor` tag like:

```
<a href="https://github.com/MonoTech71"><i class="fa-brands fa-github" /></a>
```

Or you can also do that:

```
<i class="fa-brands fa-github" onClick={() => window.open("https://github.com/MonoTech71")} />
```